# gRPC generated java files are getting duplicated or regenerated : class ClassNameGrpc is public and should be declared in a file named ClassNameGrpc

Tags: build.gradle, grpc-java

I have created a gradle java project with 2 modules :

1. grpc client module
2. grpc server module

When i build them, for some reason the grpc and protobuf files are getting generated more than once. The 2nd file is getting generated with "2" suffixed and as such throwing error as shown in screen shot below.

The gradle file is as below and this is same in client and server.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

def grpcVersion = '1.24.1'

dependencies {
compile "io.grpc:grpc-netty:${grpcVersion}"
compile "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:${grpcVersion}"
compile "io.grpc:grpc-stub:${grpcVersion}"
compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.9.2'
}

buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.10'
}
}

protobuf {
protoc {
    artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.9.2'
}
plugins {
    grpc {
        artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}"
    }
}
generateProtoTasks {
    all()*.plugins {
        grpc {}
    }
}
}


sourceSets {
main {
    java {
        srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc'
        srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
    }
}
}

jar {
manifest {
    attributes "Main-Class": "ecommerce.ecommerce.OrderMgtServer"
}
from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
}

// Generate IntelliJ IDEA's .idea & .iml project files
apply plugin: 'idea'

// Provide convenience executables for trying out the examples.
apply plugin: 'application'

startScripts.enabled = false
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible you get duplicated classes because of Gradle build output and IDE build output? If that's the case you can delegate IDE build actions to gradle ?

Answer (score 0):

Use only one `sourceSets {main { java`· added the `java` plugin and the `protobuf` plugin of your version at the `build.gradle`.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.10'
    id 'idea'
}
dependencies {
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:$grpc_version"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:$grpc_version"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-stub:$grpc_version"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-services:$grpc_version" // reflection
}
sourceSets.main.java.srcDir new File(buildDir, 'generated/source')
idea {
    module {
        // Marks the already(!) added srcDir as "generated"
        generatedSourceDirs += file('build/generated/source')
    }
}
```

After editing the `build.gradle` execute a `task -> clean` and `task -> generateProtobuff`. I think with it you fix your errors. About the `dependencies.compile` I am not sure if it affects. But I am using `dependencies.implementation`.

Comment: The 2 srcDirs are for one for 1. Protobuf Message 2. gRPC service calls. In grpc, the model builder java classes and the services both needs to generated.

Comment: that is strange. I also create my services in a different directory of the protobuf messages without this. I also use `option cc_generic_services = true;` on the protobuf files and I added the `implementation "io.grpc:grpc-services:$grpc_version"` for reflection on the `build.gradle`.